# Eloquent model not adding columns to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is a simple problem.  When I call `save()` on my model, the columns are not getting added to the database.  Here is my model:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public $email; ## string (used as username)
    public $name; ## string
    public $address; ## string
    public $phone; ## string nullable
}
```

and here's the code to add the row

```
$data=Input::all();

if ($data['password'] != $data['confirm-password']){
    return Redirect::to('/register');
}

$user = new User;

$user->email=$data['email'];
$user->password=Hash::make($data['password']);
$user->name=$data['first']." ".$data['last'];
$user->address=$data['street'].", ".$data['city'].", ".$data['state']." ".$data['zip'];
$user->phone=$data['phone'];

$user->save();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($user);
echo "</pre>";
```

The `var_dump` is outputting the proper values in the model.  Every field in the Model matches exactly the name of the column in the database.  The password hash is getting added and a new row is being created, but every other column is showing up empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `save()` function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't to declare columns as object properties. Laravel will do the magic for you.  Remove these lines:

```
public $email; ## string (used as username)
public $name; ## string
public $address; ## string
public $phone; ## string nullable
```

**Explanation:**

Laravel's Eloquent make use of PHP's `__set()` ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set)) which is triggered when you are setting to an undefined property. Laravel then performs a few internal tasks via `Model::setAttribute()` to populate the model in its own way.

See [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2940):

```
public function __set($key, $value)
{
    $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
}

public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    // First we will check for the presence of a mutator for the set operation
    // which simply lets the developers tweak the attribute as it is set on
    // the model, such as "json_encoding" an listing of data for storage.
    if ($this->hasSetMutator($key))
    {
        $method = 'set'.studly_case($key).'Attribute';

        return $this->{$method}($value);
    }

    // If an attribute is listed as a "date", we'll convert it from a DateTime
    // instance into a form proper for storage on the database tables using
    // the connection grammar's date format. We will auto set the values.
    elseif (in_array($key, $this->getDates()))
    {
        if ($value)
        {
            $value = $this->fromDateTime($value);
        }
    }

    $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I would change that to: you **can't** declare the columns as object properties.